# Measuring CPU and Memory per user to distribute "cost" of a server

Tags: monitoring, cgroups

How should I implement approximately correct per-user monitoring on a server? I want a way to split the cost of a server between the users based on their usage. On newer machines (RHEL6) I would use `cgroups`; on older kernels process accounting and `ps` averages. Are these the best ways?

Comment: I do not understand. If you already know the correct answer (cgroups, process accounting), what is your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct distribtion of costs for a user"?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring the consumption process is possible to measure the consumption of the User on the server. To measure the consumption of the process, I recommend using [Atop software](http://www.atoptool.nl).

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

```
#!/bin/bash
total_mem=0

printf "%-10s%-10s\n" User MemUsage

while read u m
do
        [[ $old_user != $u ]] && {  printf "%-10s%-0.1f\n" $old_user $total_mem;
                                    total_mem=0; }
        total_mem="$(echo $m + $total_mem | bc)"
        old_user=$u

done < <(ps --no-headers -eo user,%mem| sort -k1)

#EOF
```